# Where to get ads for my website?

Tags: seo, google, web-development, google-adsense, advertising

My website is getting around 100 visitors per day so I was thinking that I should put some ads on my website but it is really very hard to find the best advertising plan which can benefit me the most. Is Google adsense a good choice? Will google adsense allow me to open an account there with such little traffic on my website?
Please help from last two months I have done a very hard work to bring such traffic. I know it is not very much but I am still working on it.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way - but you're probably wasting your time if you only get 100/day. If you get a decent 1% click through, that's only 1 click per day and won't amount to much. Your time is better spent improving the site content and attracting more visitors :)

Answer (score 3):

You can open an account there for free, you do not have to meet any requirements. Only thing to be aware of - do not click ads on your page. Google has ways to find you and close your AdSence account.

Comment: my account is always getting rejected by google , what to do? thats why i asked for the requirement thing . . . they said i need to re sign up there after 6 months !!

Comment: You are sure that you didn't click on your own ads? This may happen from your home PC/Laptop/Smartphone or what else you got there with internet. Also they wrote clearly, your website must be at last 6 month old. Thats to prevent crazy things people were doing.

Comment: I dont have an adsence account so how can i click on my own ads kira ? 
My website is more then 6 months old and getting 100 visitors per day but no ad , so what to do i am really dissapointed and need a capital to be motivated, please help?

Answer (score 2):

AdSence is perhaps the best in terms of making revenue and the hardest to setup, they have the most strict rules.

IMO start with easier services, like [Amazon](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/)... anyway, there are many other services to try, see this for example: [40 Ways to Make Money on the Internet](http://www.dumblittleman.com/2006/10/40-ways-to-make-money-on-internet.html)